# Como faço para realizar um insert em php onde os dados são repassados por um json que possui um objeto

Tags: php, json

Como faço para realizar um insert em php onde os dados são repassados por um json que possui no objeto uma variavel não primitiva.

Esse é meu Json

```
{"id":0,"latitude":-8.0326941,"longitude":-34.9287402,"status":1, 
"tipovaga":{"descricao":"no aplication","id":5},         
 "usuario":"email":"wasleyguittar@gmail.com","id":14,"nome":"nome","palavrasecreta":"secreto","password":"XXXX"}
}
```

Esse é webservice

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO flanelinha_db.HistoricoVaga (tipo_vaga,usuario, latitude, longitude, status, endereco, bairro, cidade,   estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,? , null,null,null,null)");

$json = json_decode(include("novavaga.json"));  
$tipovaga  = $json ->{'tipovaga'};
$usuario   = $json->{'usuario'};    
$latitude    = $json->{'latitude'};
$longitude   = $json->{'longitude'};
$status     = $json->{'status'};

$stmt->bind_param("iiddi", $tipovaga, $usuario, $latitude, $longitude ,$status);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Eu preciso gravar o id das PK de tipo_vaga e usuario no banco de dados.

Comment: o json não é valido falta um "{" no "usuario"

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o json nesse caso não use `include` o certo é [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Mude:

```
$json = json_decode(include("novavaga.json"));
```

Para:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("novavaga.json"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Além disso, foi preciso usar

// o segundo paramentro converte para array 
$arr = json_decode($json,1);

e depois 
// recuperando o valor de id do tipovaga
    $tipovaga = ($arr['tipovaga']['id']);

Dessa forma resolvi o problema graças a ajuda de um colega no grupo do facebook.